# Is there a simple menu-based app that shows the LOCAL IP#?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is there a simple menu-based app that shows the LOCAL IP#? This so I can provide the IP# to anyone wanting to contact my new RPI3 on a LOCAL network (Apache web server initially).

Comment: you might also have more luck asking on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure about an independent *app*, that would integrate nicely into the raspbian gui.

I suggest you want a network status icon for your GUI, which provides this information.

I believe NetworkManager [sic] would provide this.  The GUI component for desktops which don't have anything more specific is called nm-applet.  When I used it, it was possible to right-click on it to bring up a menu, and select "details" (or maybe "info", something like that).

---

Your requirements seem a little light on explanations.

If you want to learn something as low-resource as a Pi and technical as Apache, it's not clear why you'd avoid the command-line.  `ip addr` or the original `ifconfig` commands can be useful to learn.  You may prefer `ip -4 addr` to get a single, short address.  (Offer void in a hundred years or so, when IPv4 stops being available on LANs).

Most people would set a fixed IP for the server, in co-operation with your router.

More details about what you're trying to do would be useful, to see whether there's a simpler way to achieve it.